# Large numpy array time/memory issues

Tags: python, numpy, memory, multidimensional-array

My supervisor uses IDL but I've been using Python as I'm more familiar with it. I'm performing an interpolation and have saved the lower/upper bound values. Is there a quicker way of doing this?

### Variables

Inputs:

- sed = numpy array [6,221,6900]
- it0, it1, iz0, iz1 = numpy arrays [341499]
- snapshot (38 of them)

Outputs:

- sed1, sed2, sed3, sed4 = numpy arrays [341499]

### MWE

I want to loop through the 38 snapshots, then within that loop through the 341499 particles, and then assign the resulting numpy array [6900] given below.

`sed1 = sed[iz0, it0]`
`sed2 = sed[iz1, it0]`
`sed3 = sed[iz0, it1]`
`sed4 = sed[iz1, it1]`

### What I've Tried

- I cannot initialise an array of the required size i.e. numpy [38, 341499, 4, 6900] as this gives a memory error. Meaning can't assign using vector [:] operations
- I've tried initialising a numpy dtype object array of size [38, 341499] but this very slow

Comment: Get more memory? Don't use object arrays?

Comment: But think about it, even if you use `np.int8`, it would still require `38*341499*4*690 == 358164151200` bytes, which is about 358 gigabytes of memory.

Comment: You could try to use `numpy.memmap` on a binary saved to disk. It'll require  significant amounts of memory, though. Over a terabyte for `np.float32` and almost 3 terabytes for `np.float64`

Comment: With object dtype you loose most of the fast array operations.  It has to iterate through the elements (objects) as Python speeds.  Any other way of 'chunking' your calculations?

Comment: Genius question.